# Cannot Compile C Program That Uses a Library (FFmpeg) with GCC Because of the Library's Include Statements

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ffmpeg, compilation

I am unable to compile a C project that uses a library called "FFmpeg" with a compiler called "GCC", and I believe it might be either because I don't quite understand how `#include` works or because I am using the wrong compilation process.

In a folder called `Test`, I have a file `Test/test.c` with the following contents:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "FFmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

The folder `FFmpeg` is located at `Test/FFmpeg`. When I try to compile this with GCC, I receive the following error:

```
fatal error: libavutil/samplefmt.h: No such file or directory
```

The file `Test/FFmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h` has the following code in it:

```
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"
#include "libavutil/attributes.h"
#include "libavutil/avutil.h"
... //many more #include statements
```

Is the issue here that I need to add "`FFmpeg/`" to all of these include statements?

If so, is there a way to automatically do this? This library is enormous and probably has hundreds of these statements.

If not, what should I be doing instead? Should I attempt to compile the library by itself? If so, how do I then include this compiled version of the library in my program?

---

### Notes:

- The command I am using to compile is `gcc -c test.c`.
- I have GCC installed via MinGW.
- I ultimately need to be able to compile this program to both a `.dll` and an `.so`.

---

I apologize if any of the terminology I use here is incorrect or if my explanations are poor. I know almost nothing about compilation. Please let me know if I need to fill in more information.

Comment: For a quick compilation, use "-I Test/FFmpeg". I don't recommend this as your long term solution.

Comment: No need to add `FFmpeg/` to the headers. Usually we just `#include <libavcodec/avcode.h>` directly and give gcc some option to specify where to locate additional third party headers. Besides, I think you need another option to indicate lib path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `#include` is used with quotation marks (e.g. `#include "file path here"`), it will read that file path as a **relative file path**.

In the case of compiling a C program using GCC, file paths are relative to the current directory. The "current directory" is the one into which you have placed your command prompt using the [`cd` command](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cd_(command)).

In my case, I `cd`'d into `C:/Users/User/Documents/Test`, meaning that **all** relative file paths are relative to `C:/Users/User/Documents/Test`. So when my compiler read

```
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"
```

it basically tried to do this:

```
#include C:/Users/User/Documents/Test/libavutil/samplefmt.h
```

when I instead needed the compiler to look at `…/Test/FFmpeg/libavutil/samplefmt.h`.

It turns out that the solution to this is to **give the compiler additional locations** to which relative paths might be relative. This is done with the `-I[file path here]` argument when you compile.

In my case, the way I needed to use this idea was to add `C:/Users/User/Documents/Test/FFmpeg` as a location to which paths might be relative. Thus, I could have taken my compile command:

```
gcc -c test.c
```

And inserted this:

```
gcc -IC:\Users\User\Documents\Test\FFmpeg -c test.c
```

However, this is actually an extremely clunky solution. There is a much easier way: it turns out that these file paths you provide with the `-I` argument **can be relative to your current directory themselves**. In my case, because my current directory in the command prompt was already`C:/Users/User/Documents/Test`, I could simply remove this portion from the above command, shortening it to this:

```
gcc -IFFmpeg -c test.c
```

And this solved my problem.